# Currency DisplayFor display's euro instead of usd

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using MVC 4 EF, I want to display a USD currency value but instead of "$" I got the "EURO" simbol. How can I make it appear always as "$"

Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "PaidCompany")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<decimal> paidCompany { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.paidCompany, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "login_input" }, { "style", "width:250px;" } })
```

Expected result : "$ XX.XX"
Actual result : "XXX €"

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture property is set to a culture associated with a country in the Euro zone, not to the US. By default, this property is populated according to the locale settings in windows. You can simply assign a different culture to it in your global.asax file or some other global code that runs whenever a request starts, or you can change your windows locale settings.

Edit:

Please refer to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a description of your options for setting culture.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is probably to add the following line to web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Note that UICulture is for the language of the text of your web site, whereas culture covers all the other aspects such as date and time formatting, currency symbols, etc.

Comment: Do you have any example?, I don't know exactly how to write that property on the global.asax